# Find the bottom height of a scroll div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have a div, and I need to find the maximum scroll height size of it.
My chat, currently, with 12 messages, has 800px height, but when I use this code:

```
var trueDivHeight = $('#chat')[0].scrollHeight;
```

It will only find out the height of the div, not the whole scroll to down, it will say 490px.
But I want to find the maximum height, to the bottom.

From top, to bottom of the scroll.

**Why do I need this?** to solve this bounty question by me: [AJAX Chat - Automatically drag the scroll down, but don't drag it when the user is scrolling up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235892/ajax-chat-automatically-drag-the-scroll-down-but-dont-drag-it-when-the-user)

Basically what I can do is, when sending a message, do checking:

```
if (checkScroll(trueDivHeight)) { //Runs the function checkScroll with max div height.
    scrollDown = true; // turn true if it was true.
}

if (scrollDown) {
    setInterval(function () {
        scrollToBottom(); // scroll to bottom 1 second after posted message..
    }, 1000);
}
```

and the functions I can use:

```
function scrollToBottom() {
    $('#chat').scrollTop(bottom); // Makes scroll go to the most bottom.
}

function checkScroll(size) {
    if ($("#chat").scrollTop() == size) { // Checks if current scroll position equals to the max bottom position.
        return true; // if yes, return true.
    }
}
```

*But problem is, that trueDivHeight doesn't find the whole height of the scroller, from top to bottom. if it did, then it would work for me.*

**Any ideas?**

EDIT:

```
var trueDivHeight = $('#chat')[0].scrollHeight; // finds the max bottom px
var divHeight = $('#chat').height();
var bottom = $('#chat')[0].scrollHeight;
```

Comment: What if you just used an absurdly large number? I believe that the browser will not actually scroll beyond it's bounds.

Answer (score 1):

I whipped up a little something based on my previous comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9pZ6F/2/

```
var $container = $('#container'),
    $content = $('#content'),
    $line = $('.line').clone(),
    userScrolling = false;

function setScrollTop(val) {
    $container
        .off('scroll')
        .one('scroll', function()
             {
                 $container.on('scroll', userScroll);
             })
        .scrollTop(val);
}

function scrollToNewLine() {
    if(!userScrolling) {
        setScrollTop(99999999999);
    }
}

/* Add new lines randomly */
function addNewLine() {
    var newLineTiming = Math.round(Math.random() * 3000);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $content.append($line.clone());

        scrollToNewLine();

        addNewLine();        
    }, newLineTiming);
}

addNewLine();

function userScroll() {
    userScrolling = true;

    var scrollTop = $container.scrollTop();

    setScrollTop(scrollTop + 1);

    if(scrollTop == $container.scrollTop()) {
        userScrolling = false;
    }
}

$container.on('scroll', userScroll);

$('button').on('click', function()
{
    userScrolling = false;
});
```

Comment: But it shouldn't only be upon click. It always should go down if user's scroll is located at the bottom. if not, it will not scroll down.

Comment: Updated. It now resumes autoscroll if the user scrolls to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how I did the scrolling in my chat: https://github.com/mondjunge/Crush-Framework/blob/master/javascript/chat/main.js

I get the current scrollHeight before I fetch the data. After fetching potentially new messages I check if the scrollHeight got bigger and only do scroll to the bottom if so. This way the user is able to scroll as long as no new message pops up.

Here is the code:

```
function getData() {
var oldscrollHeight = $("#chatWindow").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
var room = $("#chatRoom").val();
var chatUrl = "?m=load&room="+room;

if(!firstRun){
    //alert("something");
    chatUrl = "?m=idle&room="+room;
}       

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: chatUrl,
    async: true,
    timeout: 30000,
    data: "get=true",
    success: function(html){
        var htmlArr = html.split('<!--USERLIST-->');
        //alert(htmlArr[1]);
        $("#userList").html(htmlArr[1]);
        if(firstRun){

            $("#chatWindow").html(htmlArr[0]);
            firstRun = false;
        }else{
            $("#chatWindow").append(htmlArr[0]);
        // alert('idle');
        }

        //$("#chatWindow").html(html);
        //Insert chat log into the #chatbox div             
        var newscrollHeight = $("#chatWindow").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
        if(newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight){
            $("#chatWindow").animate({
                scrollTop: newscrollHeight
            }, 'normal'); //Autoscroll to bottom of div
        }

        setTimeout("getData()", 1000);

    }
});
```

I hope I understood your problem. I believe this don't really answer the question, but I am sure that you are on a false way with your implementation if you scroll every time you fetch data. Keep triggered events as few as possible.

Comment: Would be better if you could explain more, and post the specific code that does the scrolling there mate, would help a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for the edit. But it doesn't seem to work for me. http://pastebin.com/f0Qvh8Ug Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: I don't see any fetching of new data that is inserted in the #chat div you get the scroll height from. You need to get the scroll height before you fetch new messages and check and scroll after you inserted them into the chat div.

Comment: reload() reloads the whole thing.

Comment: Also, it gives me NaN when i log newscrollHeight and old

Answer (score 0):

My solution is similar to Mondjudge, but different in a few ways.

I need the current position of the scroll, not the whole!

My reload:

```
function reload() {
    var oldscrollHeight = ($("#chat").scrollTop() + 470);
    console.log(" old: " + oldscrollHeight);
    $.post("ajax.php", { loadMessages : "1" }, function(data) {
        $(".discussion").html(data); 
        var newscrollHeight = $("#chat").prop("scrollHeight");
        console.log(" new: " + newscrollHeight);
        if(newscrollHeight < (oldscrollHeight + 150)) {
            var height = $('#chat')[0].scrollHeight;
            $('#chat').scrollTop(height);
        }           
    });     
}
```